# Custom debounce function not working with anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm trying to create a custom debounce function:

```
const debounced = [];

const cancelFunc = timeout => () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};

function debounce(fn, wait, ...args) {  
  let d = debounced.find(({ func }) => func === fn);

  if (d) {
    d.cancel();  
  } else {
    d = {};
    debounced.push(d);
  }

  d.func = fn;   
  d.timeout = setTimeout(fn, wait, ...args);
  d.cancel = cancelFunc(d.timeout);
}
```

If I use with a named function, it works as intended:

```
debounce(foo, 1000); // called once with 5 clicks in 1 second
```

But I can't get it to work with anonymous functions:

```
debounce(() => { foo(5); }, 1000); // called 5 times with 5 clicks in 1 second
```

I created a pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQvMdR?editors=1011

Comment: Each call creates a separate function, so you won't find it in the array.

Comment: This is why it's usually a bad idea to roll your own.

Comment: This is mostly for learning purposes, I don't understand the downvote. Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @SLaks *"Each call creates a separate function, so you won't find it in the array."*

So you just need to store something in the array to match it to, you can use `.toString()`

```js
// ================

const debounced = [];

const cancelFunc = timeout => () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};

function debounce(fn, wait, ...args) {
  let d = debounced.find(({ funcString }) => funcString === fn.toString());

  if (d) {
    d.cancel();
  } else {
    d = {};
    debounced.push(d);
  }

  d.func = fn;
  d.funcString = fn.toString()
  d.timeout = setTimeout(fn, wait, ...args);
  d.cancel = cancelFunc(d.timeout);
}

// ================

function foo(value) {
 console.log('value:', value)
}

function onClickBroken() {
  debounce(() => { foo(5); }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="onClickBroken()">Click me 5 times</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of your `find` condition. Let's back up, and consider this bit of code:

```
if (
    (function(){ return 1 }) === (function(){ return 1 })
) {
    console.log('The functions are equal');
} else {
    console.log('The functions are NOT equal');
}

// logs 'The functions are NOT equal'
```

Even though I wrote two identical anonymous functions, they are *not* strictly equal to each other. When you pass in that anonymous function, that is essentially what you are doing. So, when you search for your array for a previously found function, it will never find a match, because each time `debounce(() => { foo(5); }, 1000);` is called it **creates a new function**. Since it'll never find a match, it will never be canceled.